# Python Speech Recognition KeyError BufferedReader

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech

I am transcoding some audio files using the speech recognition package in Python, and I am getting a KeyError (io.BufferedReader) when I am recording the file. I am not really sure what it means or how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Below are my code and error.

```
import speech_recognition as sr 

r = sr.Recognizer()

AudioFile = sr.AudioFile('/Users/USERNAME/Audio_file.wav')
with AudioFile as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
```

Expected results:
string variable with the audio transcript.
**Actual results: The following error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>   
File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda2/envs/python_sr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py",line 295, in __exit__ self.audio_reader.close()   
File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda2/envs/python_sr/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 194, in close file.close()   File "<string>", line 131, in close 
KeyError: <_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/USERNAME/Audio_file.wav'>
```

Comment: well are you sure you have a file called `Audio_file.wav` ?

Comment: Is the path to `AudioFile` correct? try giving the full path.

Comment: @painor Yes the file exists.

Comment: Restarting seems to have worked for now, but a more thorough solution (and explanation perhaps) would be greatly appreciated.